# Dynamic CRM 2011 uninstall erro: Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in

Tags: crm, uninstallation

There is an error when I trying to uninstall Dynamic CRM 2011 (version 6.0.0.0),
one error is:

```
08:41:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
08:41:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
```

**another error is:**

```
08:39:45|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
```

**as below,**

```
09:22:21|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 28/6/2016 9:22:21 AM ===
09:22:21|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
09:22:21|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXXXX.
09:22:21|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Desktop\CRM\SetupClient.exe" 
09:22:21|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\Desktop\CRM
09:22:21|   Info| Loading bootstrap library ClientSetup.dll
09:22:21|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
09:22:24|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
09:22:24|   Info| InputResult: Yes
09:22:26|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 28/6/2016 9:22:26 AM ===

09:22:24|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
09:22:24|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
09:22:24|   Info| Initializing COM.
09:22:24|   Info| Initialized COM.
09:22:24|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
09:22:24|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
09:22:24|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
09:22:24|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
09:22:24|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
09:22:27|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 28/6/2016 9:22:26 AM ===
09:22:26|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
09:22:26|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
09:22:26|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
09:22:27|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

09:22:27|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

09:22:27|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 28/6/2016 9:22:27 AM ===
08:23:14|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:23:14 AM ===
08:23:14|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:23:14|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
08:23:14|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
08:23:14|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
08:23:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
08:23:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
08:23:15|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
08:23:15|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:39:45|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
08:39:45|   Info| InputResult: Yes
08:39:47|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:39:47 AM ===

08:39:45|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:39:45|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
08:39:45|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:39:45|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:39:45|   Info| Disk Space Available: 3878.00MB
08:39:45|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:39:45|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:39:45|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:39:45|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:39:45|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
08:39:49|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:39:47 AM ===
08:39:47|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:39:47|   Info| User: XXXXXXXX.
08:39:47|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
08:39:49|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:39:49|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:39:49|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:39:49 AM ===
08:40:11|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:40:11 AM ===
08:40:11|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:40:11|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXX.
08:40:11|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Users\XXXXXX\SetupClient.exe"
08:40:11|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Users\XXXXXX
08:40:11|   Info| Loading bootstrap library ClientSetup.dll
08:40:11|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:40:16|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
08:40:16|   Info| InputResult: Yes
08:40:18|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:40:18 AM ===

08:40:16|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:40:16|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXX.
08:40:16|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:40:16|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:40:16|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:40:16|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:40:16|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:40:16|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:40:16|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
08:40:51|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:40:18 AM ===
08:40:18|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:40:18|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:40:18|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
08:40:51|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:40:51|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:40:51|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:40:51 AM ===
08:41:15|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:41:15 AM ===
08:41:15|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:41:15|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
08:41:15|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
08:41:15|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
08:41:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
08:41:15|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
08:41:15|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
08:41:15|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:41:24|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:41:24 AM ===

08:41:22|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:41:22|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:41:22|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:41:22|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:41:22|   Info| Disk Space Available: 3650.00MB
08:41:22|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:41:22|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:41:22|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:41:22|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:41:22|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
08:41:48|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:41:24 AM ===
08:41:24|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:41:24|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:41:24|  Error| Repair of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
08:41:48|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:41:48|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:41:48|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:41:48 AM ===
08:42:00|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:42:00 AM ===
08:42:00|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:42:00|   Info| User: XXXXXXXX.
08:42:00|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Users\XXXXXX\SetupClient.exe"
08:42:00|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Users\XXXXX
08:42:00|   Info| Loading bootstrap library ClientSetup.dll
08:42:00|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:42:06|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:42:06 AM ===

08:42:04|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:42:04|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
08:42:04|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:42:04|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:42:04|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:42:04|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:42:04|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:42:04|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:42:04|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
08:42:08|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:42:06 AM ===
08:42:06|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.1992.
08:42:06|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:42:06|  Error| Repair of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
08:42:08|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:42:08|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:42:08|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:42:08 AM ===
08:42:34|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:42:34 AM ===
08:42:34|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:42:34|   Info| User: XXXXXXXX.
08:42:34|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
08:42:34|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
08:42:35|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
08:42:35|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
08:42:35|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
08:42:35|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:42:41|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
08:42:41|   Info| InputResult: Yes
08:42:43|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:42:43 AM ===

08:42:41|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:42:41|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:42:41|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:42:41|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:42:41|   Info| Disk Space Available: 3491.00MB
08:42:41|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:42:41|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:42:41|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:42:41|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:42:41|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
08:42:45|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:42:43 AM ===
08:42:43|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:42:43|   Info| User: XXXXXXXX.
08:42:43|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
08:42:45|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:42:45|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

08:42:45|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:42:45 AM ===
08:43:31|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 8:43:31 AM ===
08:43:31|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:43:31|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
08:43:31|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
08:43:31|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
08:43:31|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
08:43:31|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
08:43:31|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
08:43:31|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
08:43:41|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
08:43:41|   Info| InputResult: Yes
08:43:43|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 8:43:43 AM ===

08:43:41|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:43:41|   Info| User: XXXXXXXXg.
08:43:41|   Info| Initializing COM.
08:43:41|   Info| Initialized COM.
08:43:41|   Info| Disk Space Available: 3230.00MB
08:43:41|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
08:43:41|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
08:43:41|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
08:43:41|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
08:43:41|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
09:15:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 8:43:43 AM ===
08:43:43|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
08:43:43|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
08:43:43|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
09:15:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

09:15:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

09:15:44|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 9:15:44 AM ===
09:19:03|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 9:19:03 AM ===
09:19:04|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
09:19:04|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
09:19:04|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
09:19:04|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
09:19:04|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
09:19:04|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
09:19:04|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
09:19:04|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
09:19:11|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
09:19:11|   Info| InputResult: Yes
09:19:12|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 9:19:12 AM ===

09:19:11|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
09:19:11|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
09:19:11|   Info| Initializing COM.
09:19:11|   Info| Initialized COM.
09:19:11|   Info| Disk Space Available: 3044.00MB
09:19:11|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
09:19:11|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
09:19:11|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
09:19:11|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
09:19:11|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
10:00:40|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 9:19:12 AM ===
09:19:12|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
09:19:12|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
09:19:12|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
10:00:40|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:00:40|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:00:40|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:00:40 AM ===
10:09:25|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 10:09:25 AM ===
10:09:25|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:09:25|   Info| User: XXXXXXXX.
10:09:25|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
10:09:25|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
10:09:25|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
10:09:25|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
10:09:25|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
10:09:25|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
10:10:38|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
10:10:38|   Info| InputResult: Yes
10:10:40|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:10:40 AM ===

10:10:38|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:10:38|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:10:38|   Info| Initializing COM.
10:10:38|   Info| Initialized COM.
10:10:38|   Info| Disk Space Available: 2866.00MB
10:10:38|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
10:10:38|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
10:10:38|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
10:10:38|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
10:10:38|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
10:13:57|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 10:10:40 AM ===
10:10:40|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:10:40|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:10:40|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
10:13:57|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:13:57|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:13:57|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:13:57 AM ===
10:23:33|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 10:23:33 AM ===
10:23:33|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:23:33|   Info| User: XXXXXX.
10:23:33|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
10:23:33|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
10:23:33|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
10:23:33|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
10:23:33|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
10:23:33|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
10:23:38|   Info| Are you sure you want to remove Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook from this computer?, Question, Yes|No
10:23:38|   Info| InputResult: Yes
10:23:40|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:23:40 AM ===

10:23:38|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:23:38|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:23:38|   Info| Initializing COM.
10:23:38|   Info| Initialized COM.
10:23:38|   Info| Disk Space Available: 2639.00MB
10:23:38|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
10:23:38|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
10:23:38|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
10:23:38|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
10:23:38|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
10:23:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

ted 29/6/2016 10:23:40 AM ===
10:23:40|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:23:40|   Info| User:XXXXXXX.
10:23:40|  Error| Uninstall of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
10:23:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:23:44|   Info| Clean up the BITS downloader.

10:23:44|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:23:44 AM ===
10:24:21|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 10:24:21 AM ===
10:24:21|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:24:21|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:24:21|   Info| Invoked with command line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\SetupClient.exe" /usersid S-1-5-21-1995084360-4069634646-2440262340-1007 /dontsetuninstallregkeys
10:24:21|   Info| Running Microsoft Dynamic CRM 5 for Outlook at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client
10:24:21|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because no bootstrap DLL is present in . (bootstrapWrapper.h:CBootstrapLibrary::Locate:330).
10:24:21|  Error| Setup cannot proceed because  cannot be found or is incorrect. (clientbootstrapwrapper.cpp:CClientBootstrapLibrary::Load:46).
10:24:21|   Info| Loading bootstrap library C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\ClientSetup.dll
10:24:21|   Info| Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook is already installed.
10:24:27|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging ended 29/6/2016 10:24:27 AM ===

10:24:26|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:24:26|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:24:26|   Info| Initializing COM.
10:24:26|   Info| Initialized COM.
10:24:26|   Info| Disk Space Available: 2639.00MB
10:24:26|  Error| MsiOpenPackage failed while trying to read property ProductLanguage
10:24:26|  Error| MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed.(error = 2) (msiutility.cpp:CMsiUtility::GetProductProperty:264).
10:24:26|   Info| Uninitializing COM.
10:24:26|   Info| Uninitialized COM.
10:24:26|   Info| Error in Run client bootstrap : MsiOpenPackage(C:\windows\Installer\14bae98.msi) failed..
10:24:27|   Info| === Setup bootstrap logging started 29/6/2016 10:24:27 AM ===
10:24:27|   Info| Bootstrap version: 5.0.9690.4376.
10:24:27|   Info| User: XXXXXXX.
10:24:27|  Error| Repair of Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook failed.
```

What is the issue, and how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to uninstall the outlook client. A quick Google suggests [that you should activate Windows Identity Foundation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/869a1975-2331-46b0-89f6-098a3a0f4ab2/crm-2011?forum=W8ITProPreRel), then restart and try again. Also there is a guide for this; [Step by step to uninstall the Dynamics CRM Outlook Client successfull](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadcrmsupport/2014/02/06/step-by-step-to-uninstall-the-dynamics-crm-outlook-client-successfully/)y.

Comment: @MooreZhang, if my answer has been helpful, typically you up vote or accept the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my problem by uninstalling CRM manually, follow the links below,
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadcrmsupport/2014/02/06/step-by-step-to-uninstall-the-dynamics-crm-outlook-client-successfully/

Best wishes.